# Sumar el valor de cada periodo y poner 0 en los periodos que no existan en tabla SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, datatables, join, group-by

Tengo dos tablas Ingresos y Periodos, dentro de la tabla Periodos están los meses de enero a febrero y en Ingresos tengo una columna valor_aporte en la que hay registros para lo que se ha aportado en cada mes. 
ej.

```
Ingresos
Periodo Valor_aporte
---------------------  
Enero   10
Enero   20
Febrero 30
Marzo   40
Marzo   50
```

Lo que quiero hacer es una consulta que devuelva la suma del Valor_aporte para cada periodo, incluso si la tabla Ingresos no tiene un Periodo específico, cuando eso suceda debe llenarse con 0, es decir, con el ejemplo anterior debería devolverse algo así.

```
Periodo Suma_Aporte
-------------------
Enero     30
Febrero   30
Marzo     90
Abril     0
Mayo      0
.....
Diciembre 0
```

Esta es la consulta que tengo hasta el momento

```
 SELECT P.PERIODO,
  (SELECT SUM(ING.VALOR_APORTE)
  FROM INGRESOS ING2
  WHERE ING2.PERIODO = ING.PERIODO
  ) AS SUMA
FROM PERIODOS P
LEFT JOIN INGRESOS ING
ON p.PERIODO            =ING.PERIODO 
GROUP BY 
  p.PERIODO;
```

Pero solo estoy obteniendo los periodos que existen en la tabla Ingresos, así:

```
Periodo Suma_Aporte
    -------------------
    Enero     30
    Febrero   30
    Marzo     90
```

Comment: para el caso de los meses que no te muestra, esta condición de tu sql se cumple? ON p.PERIODO            =ING.PERIODO

Comment: Si se cumple, si dejo la condición imprime solamente los meses que existen en la tabla ingresos, si quito la condición, me aparecen todos los meses, pero la suma queda mal ya que suma toda la columna VALOR_APORTE

Comment: cambia el left join por FULL JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Esto tal vez?

```
SELECT P.PERIODO,
       NVL(SUM(ING.VALOR_APORTE),0) AS 'TOTAL_APORTE'
       FROM PERIODOS P
       LEFT JOIN INGRESOS ING
            ON P.PERIODO = ING.PERIODO
       GROUP BY P.PERIODO;
```

Siempre que `PERIODOS` sea una tabla con los 12 meses. Usamos `NVL()` para retornar 0 en caso de valor `NULL`.

Comment: Hola Patricio, siguen sin salir los que no están en la tabla INGRESOS, salen solamente los Periodos que aparezcan tanto en PERIODOS como en INGRESOS

Comment: Seguro que tienes 12 periodos en la tabla periodos? Es lo único que alcanzó a imaginar sea el motivo de lo que comentas. La idea del LEFT JOIN es justamente todos los registros de una tabla y solo los que coinciden de la otra.

Comment: En el enunciado no dice en ninguna parte que haya 12 periodos en la tabla: ...dentro de la tabla Periodos están los meses de enero a febrero...

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente dire que una tabla de periodos con 12 registros de Enero a Diciembre es algo que se desaconseja, esto principalmente por que los meses del año siempre son 12 y por lo mismo no merece la pena guardarlos.

Dicho lo anterior te propongo la siguiente solución en ella se generan los 12 periodos al vuelo y ya posterior se cruzan contra los ingresos.

```
 WITH TTPERIODOS AS (
    SELECT LEVEL PERIODO
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
), TTINGRESOS AS (
    SELECT SUM(VALOR_APORTE) SUMA
         , PERIODO
      FROM INGRESOS     
  GROUP BY PERIODO
 )  SELECT p.PERIODO
         , NVL(ing.SUMA, 0)
      FROM TTPERIODOS p
   LEFT  JOIN TTINGRESOS ing
        ON ing.PERIODO = p.PERIODO
        ORDER BY PERIODO;
```